# jQuery, JSON objects and .NET WebServices

Tags: c#, javascript, json, web-services, jquery

I have a question about creating JSON from JQuery, sending the same by Ajax to a webservice in .NET, and how to deserialize in .NET and save to the database.

Maybe someone can give me a hand to see where I'm mistaken!

### jQuery and JSON:

```
var myObject = {};

//** BusinessPartner **
//function BusinessPartner(prefix) {
//    this.bpCodigo = $(prefix + " option:selected").val();
//    this.bpNombre = $(prefix + "-infonombre").text();
//
//** Locations **
//function Locations(prefix) {
//    this.locCode = $(prefix + " option:selected").val();
//    this.locName = $(prefix + "-name").text();

var oNewObject = new BusinessPartner("#bp-01");
var oNewObject2 = new BusinessPartner("#bp-02");

var myLocation = [];
var oOrigin = new Locations("#receipt");
myLocation.push(oOrigin);
var oDestination = new Locations("#portloading");
myLocation.push(oOrigin);

myObject["Agent1"] = oNewObject;
myObject["Agent2"] = oNewObject;
myObject["Locations"] = myLocation;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Services/ActionsDb.asmx/saveData",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(myObject),
    datatype: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        // After correct save send OK message.
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        alert("An error occurred: " + status);
    }
});
```

### The class in C# .NET

As I understand it, that should have exactly the same format as JSON received by the webservice.

```
public class Agent
{
    public string bpCodigo { get; set; }
    public string bpNombre { get; set; }
}
public class Location 
{
    public string locCode { get; set; }
    public string locName { get; set; }
}
public class oGet
{
    public Agent oCliente { get; set; }
    public Agent oCliente2 { get; set; }
    public List<Location> oLocations { get; set; }
}
```

### Webservice

Good, now the WebService ActionsDb.asmx / savedata that will be asked to save the data in the DB.

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string saveData(oGet myObject)
    {
        try
        {
            string sClienteName = myObject.oCliente.bpNombre.ToString();
            return sClienteName.ToString();

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
```

### Result

The error I get follows:

```
POST http://localhost:8869/Services/WebtoolActionsDb.asmx/saveBLData 500 (Internal Server Error)    
{"Message":"Service call not valid. Parameter missing: \u0027myObject\u0027.","StackTrace":" 
en System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters) 
en System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters) 
en System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)
en System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

Comment: what happens if you `JSON.parse(myObject)`?

Comment: Could you translate that error message to english please. Also in future please only use the english language on our site. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your JavaScript. The reason you're getting a 500 error is because the JSON you're sending needs to have a "myObject" property to correspond with the parameter to `saveData`. You also need to change "Agent1" to "oCliente", "Agent2" to "oCliente2", and "Locations" to "oLocations" in order to match the properties in `oGet`.

```
myObject.oCliente = oNewObject;
myObject.oCliente2 = oNewObject2;
myObject.oLocations = myLocation;

$.ajax({
    // ...
    data: JSON.stringify({ myObject: myObject }),
    // ...
});
```